# What is 'only' when used with a linking verb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, copular-verbs, only

What about "you are only a boy"? Some claim only modifies are, is this an "exception" to the copula taking adjectives rather than adverbs? (I can appreciate the objection to the insistence on the distinction!)